# "Hello, World" PHP page is not working

Tags: php

I am trying to start programming in PHP. I found this example ["Hello, World"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) PHP page.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, instead of displaying:

```
Hello World
```

It displays:

```
Hello World
'; ?>
```

Viewing the source shows

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

instead of

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

So it looks like it did not get parsed by Chrome. What is causing this problem?

Comment: How should I try to view the page?

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. [Take a look here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.requirements.php) on what you need. If you want a quick and easy system to get started on, take a look at [Usbwebserver](http://www.usbwebserver.net/).

Comment: Seeing that you are starting to program with PHP, I can't stress enough the importance of really familiarizing yourself with the concepts of (and differences between) client-side and server-side (if you haven't already) in this early stage. It's invaluable information in understanding some of the key concepts in web development.

Comment: "did not get parsed by chrome" -> Chrome does not process PHP. Chrome only parses client-side languages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure the file is named .php and not .html or .htm.  Also make sure you have uploaded it to a PHP web server.

Chrome (or any browser) does not parse PHP at all... the server parses the PHP and passes the HTML to the browser. Bottom line, the browser should never know PHP exists.

Comment: +1 I tried op's code with .html got his results changed to .php and all good

Comment: Alternatively, you can tell the server to process HTML files as PHP files: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like PHP isn't installed on your web server or you just opened the page directly off of your file system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until somebody helped me out. Do this:

Access the file from your browser like so: http:// (localhost) /hello.php and it will come up fine provided your [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP), [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP), etc. is running online and shows green. Remove spaces and parentheses around localhost). Also the file must be in the `www` directory of your `Wamp`, etc. folder in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose you should put your code into php file make helloworld.php file 
and put in wamp www folder and run with wamp server.
for hello world program in php just follow this tutorial
but before that you should have wamp server or xamp server on your pc
(wamp/xmap are open source software's and easily can found on google)
your 1st php program code:-

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

output:-
hello world
Helping Step by Step Tutorial :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qtqzhdEX-c 
after this tutorial you can able to move other intermediate level programs of php.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you've used the same type of quotes - `"` and `'` are completely different beasts.

Comment: The OP shows the quotes he uses. They are the same.