# Does window.onclick not work for .php files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, window, alert

I have following php code in jk.php :

```
<?php
echo "<script src='./rfjs.js'></script>";
?>
```

And content of the rfjs.js is :

```
window.onclick = function(){
    alert ('Hey!');
}
```

When I open jk.php and click over the window, alert does not show up as expected.
However, if I use an HTML file instead, all works well.

For example, here is my rf.html file :

```
<script src='./rfjs.js'></script>
```

When I open it and click somewhere, it shows the alert message as expected. What is the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: Did check the browser developer console and did you take any error message ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Hello, World" PHP page is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608468/hello-world-php-page-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

When you open you php file, right click and click view source is there any data at all? If no the php is not recognising the echo or php not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code the same way that you've done in the php and it works fine for me. But what I noticed here is the path you've given is "./rfjs.js" in the `src` of `<script></script>` tag. If your "rfjs.js" resides in the same place as your "jk.php", then no need to put a "./" before your "rfjs.js" file, and if it resides in some other directory, then try giving that path as "xyz/rfjs.js". Try replacing it with `<script src="rfjs.js"></script>`

Also make sure you have uploaded it to a PHP web server.
Chrome (or any browser) does not parse PHP at all. The server parses the PHP and passes the HTML to the browser. Bottom line, the browser should never know PHP exists. .Hope this helps.